# $request->validate(), ni FormRequest no me funciona. Me manda la pagina de laravel welcome cuando no pasa la regla

Tags: laravel

Estoy tratando de trabajar con Form request y validate. Al momento de usarlo, cuando entra a la excepción me manda una respuesta en html, con la pagina de welcome de laravel. Adjunto codigo y la respuesta

```
 $request->validate([
        'document_number' => 'bail|required|min:5|unique:users',
        'name' => 'required|min:3',
        'last_name' => 'required|min:3',
        'email' => 'required|min:5|unique:users',
    ]);
```

tambien intente con el form request y nada

de esta menra tambien

```
$rules = [
        'document_number' => 'bail|required|min:5|unique:users',
        'name' => 'required|min:3',
        'last_name' => 'required|min:3',
        'email' => 'required|min:5|unique:users',
    ];
    $this->validate($request, $rules);
```

respuesta de la api

[image: dd]

Comment: Podrías poner el controlador completo de lo que estás haciendo?

Comment: En postman tienes que agregar el header "Accept: application/json", de otra forma no vas a obtener una respuesta de laravel en json

Comment: Gracias @porloscerrosΨ esto me ayudo!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo era añadir en postman el Accept: application/json. con esto se soluciona todo